# How do i action a button in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyuic

This this the code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox
import Editor
import sys

class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Editor.Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.infoGet)

    def infoGet(self, any, mode):
        vFN = self.lineEdit.text()
        vMN = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        vLN = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        vID = self.lineEdit_4.text()
        print(vFN)
```

Hope you guys figure it out!!

So i use `self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.infoGet)` as a action code.
`pushButton` is my button object. And I get...
  `File "d:\**--CENSORED--**\edui.py", line 25, in <module> mapp = MyApp() File "d:\folder visead\RAIN FORREST\Data Base\Citizen record\edui.py", line 12, in __init__ self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.infoGet) #!TES{PIGOFSDOPPOIHBSJ} AttributeError: 'MyApp' object has no attribute 'pushButton'`

I don't know why I got attibute error btw.

Comment: Typo: change `self.pushButton` to `self.ui.pushButton`. You're using composition, so ui elements are member of the `self.ui` object. If you used multiple inheritance, you'd have used `self.setupUi(self)` and then all attributes would be directly in `self`. Try to open that Ui_Form class and read what it does in `setupUi()` with its argument.

Comment: Also, avoid profanity, it's unnecessary and uncalled for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your pushButton is inside `self.ui = Editor.Ui_Form()`. Therefore, to access pushButton you have to use `self.ui` instead of `self`. Following code might be the solution to your problem:

```
class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Editor.Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.infoGet) # Update this

    def infoGet(self, any, mode):
        vFN = self.ui.lineEdit.text() # Update this
        vMN = self.ui.lineEdit_2.text() # Update this
        vLN = self.ui.lineEdit_3.text() # Update this
        vID = self.ui.lineEdit_4.text() # Update this
        print(vFN)
```